# Xilinx XPS does not shown user IP cores, not even when IP core is generated in XPS; how to make it?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-system-generator

The Xilinx XPS (part of EDK) should have a list of IP cores present in the directory structure that I searches, but there are none, as seen in the figure below where the red ring indicates where the list of IP cores should be:

[image]

Even if I create an IP core template using Hardware => Create or Import Peripheral... feature, as seen in figure below, the create IP core template does not show up for use in XPS.

[image]

How can I get access in XPS to the collection of IP cores that I have?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled all Xilinx SW on the PC (Win 7 x64), and manually removed (almost) all entries in the Registry related to Xilinx, and then reinstalled Xilinx ISE ver. 14.7, and then XPS now shows the cores correctly.